# Запуск и остановка служб в Linux Mint

Tags: linux, service

Какими командами останавливаются/запускаются службы в *Linux Mint*?

P.S. Разобрался:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/name_service stop/start
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бо́льшую часть служб можно запустить/перезапустить/остановить командой

```
service SERVICE_NAME start/restart/stop
```

Но некоторые такому управлению не поддаются и нужно использовать другие команды:

```
/etc/init.d/SERVICE_NAME start/restart/stop
```

Естественно, что это придётся выполнять с правами *root*.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.